# Is there any way that I can covert bar to circle in D3 JS

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 JS and looking for a customize solution which is not available out of the box in d3 JS.

Below code produced a bar chart which denotes no. of students against 3 different classes,

Question, Can I show **Circle instead of bar**? please suggest some code? Thanks!

```
//data
    let data = [{ "noOfStudents": 30, "ClassName": "Class 1" }, { "noOfStudents": 42, "ClassName": "Class 2" }, { "noOfStudents": 38, "ClassName": "Class 3" }];
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // get and format the data
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.noOfStudents = +d.noOfStudents;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data in the domains
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.ClassName; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.noOfStudents; })]);

    // append the rectangles for the bar chart
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.ClassName); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.noOfStudents); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.noOfStudents); })
        .text(function (d) { return d.noOfStudents; });

    // add the x Axis
    svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // add the y Axis
    svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Comment: Just a tip: if you're looking for customised and "out of the box" solutions, don't use d3, use an easier chart library or, even better, some library/framework built on top of d3 (such as c3, dc, nvd3, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rectangles, just append circles:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.ClassName); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.noOfStudents); })
    .attr("r", 30)
    .text(function (d) { return d.noOfStudents; });
```

And change your band scale for a point scale:

```
var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0.4);
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kks4gcL3/

Comment: Just one question, can we make Y-Scale bigger than 40, as one circle is partial due to this?

Comment: Hi again, can we add click event to each circle, may be each circle will convert to a pie with different data?

Comment: This is a completely *different* problem. Please post it as *another* question.